# How to add a google plus-one tag <g:plusone> with haml

Tags: haml, google-plus-one

How I could add a Google +1 button in haml?

The result should look something like

```
<g:plusone annotation="inline"></g:plusone>
```

This tag is then replaced with the actual button with a piece of javascript that Google offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Google +1, but to generate such `html` you can use this `haml` code:

```
%g:plusone{:annotation => "inline"}
```

Comment: I'm using haml with ruby on rails application and I needed to change the ( ) to { }.